Active Directory query
I have an Active Directory query which is searching printers in AD:
[CommonQuery]
Handler=5EE6238AC231D011891C00A024AB2DBBC1
Form=70F077B5E27ED011913F00AA00C16E65DB
[DsQuery]
ViewMode=0413000017
EnableFilter=0000000000

I save it as find_printers.qds. When that file is started, it opens a window and lists the printers that are published in AD.
Now I would like to change the query to find users, not printers. Does anyone know what I need to change to search users instead of printers?

Just run rundll32 dsquery,OpenQueryWindow and the default search box opens up that'll search for Users, Contacts and Groups in the directory. You can do File > Save Search if you want the QDS file. Or if you want a logged-on user to be able to search for themselves, this script supposedly generates a file that'll do it: https://gist.github.com/maphew/027d0d9d8913afcc562a
